# how to generate hash value from signature string?

Tags: php, hmacsha1

I am trying to use api access for my local provider, as api documentation said I have to send post's parameters also with hash value to api gate way. Api gate way returns me 010 error, when I mailed that error to them they said hash value error. As api documentation said I have to sort all input parameters in post by ascii to create signature string, and then convert signature string with hash_mac by user secret key. I am confusing with "sorting all input parameters by ascii" what does mean. Any explanation is greatly appreciated.

Documentation said - 
Hash value computed by HMACSHA1 with secret key provided by provider. HashValue will be generated by the following methods:
1. All the input parameters, which are filled in by customer, are sorted by ASCII to be Signature String.
2. Signature String will be encrypted by HMACSHA1 with secret key provided 
by provider.

Api sample code for generating hash value

```
<?php
$signData = hash_hmac('sha1', 
SignatureString,Secret Key, false);
$signData= strtoupper($signData);
echo urlencode($signData);
?>
```

User input paramenters

```
<form action="http://121.143.168.11/Payment/Payment/pay" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="merchantID" name="merchantID" value="382987634198262"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="invoiceNo" name="invoiceNo" value="0345"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="productDesc" name="productDesc" value="TESTProduct"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="000000010000"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="currencyCode" name="currencyCode" value="104"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="categoryCode" name="categoryCode" value="000012"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="userDefined1" name="userDefined1" value="UserDefined1"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="userDefined2" name="userDefined2" value="UserDefined2"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="userDefined3" name="userDefined3" value="UserDefined3"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="hashValue" name="hashValue" value="BA115F06B0629EC69EDBA33604301B891D5C9F8C"/>
/>
```

My question is how could I generate signature string for above user input parameters.

Thanks

Comment: What payment gateway are you using?

Comment: Local MPU payment gateway in Burmar,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you submit this form via POST, and that POST variables don't contain any garbage, and that I understand the "sorted by" instruction correctly:

```
$secret = 'XXXXXX';
ksort($_POST); // sort by input names alphabetically
$signature_source = '';
foreach ($_POST as $value) {
    $signature_source .= $value;
}
$signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $signature_source, $secret, false);
```

No need to apply `urlencode()` to it, unless there's something else in the picture that I'm missing.

Comment: I replaced my code sorting method with ksort() to get $signature_source, but it is seem to me this sorting method(ksort) might generate wrong formate for $signature_source, so I can't get right Hash value ($signature) from hash_hmac and server returns error for Hash value. Documentation said I have to sort parameters in post by ASCII Code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_form_data = array(
    'merchantID' => '400123456712345',
    'invoiceNo' => '1234567890333',
    'productDesc' => 'Test Product',
    'amount' => '000000010000',
    'currencyCode' => 840,
    'userDefined1' => 'userDefined1',
    'userDefined2' => 'userDefined2',
    'userDefined3' => 'userDefined3',
);

function getPaymentHash($data)
{
    asort($data, SORT_STRING); // sorting values by ASCII
    $str = implode('', $data);
    $signData = hash_hmac('sha1', $str, 'secret key', false);
    $signData = strtoupper($signData);
    return urlencode($signData);
}

$hashValue = getPaymentHash($_form_data);
```

good luck :)